# Error: .NET Framework 4.7.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 for my Visual Studio solution but it tells me that **.NET Framework 4.7.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer**.

Comment: try this   :stackoverflow.com/a/75883840/11780141

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must install the Developer Pack of .NET Framework 4.7.2.

You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks).

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything ranging from offline installer to web installer but nothing worked.
Finally I was able to install required things using Individual Components section of Visual Studio Installer.

i.e. Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual Components

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The SDK/Developer Pack and the Runtime are not the same. 
You can install necessary versions using Visual Studio Installer.[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Comment: Yes, I tried everything, offline installer, web installer etc. But finally able to install required components via visual studio installer *Individual Components* section.